# How to get While to Return a Custom Value?

Tags: functions, return-value

The Documentation for While says:

> Unless an explicit Return is used, the value returned by While is Null.

But how do I implement it? I'd like to build a function  `f[..., k_:0]:= While[test(k), k++; ...]` that tests a condition against increasing values of k starting from zero and eventually returns the value that makes test(k) return `False` (or `True`).

Comment: `k` in your function is going to be a number (zero by default), not a variable, and so the statement `k++` cannot be evaluated and will throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. The condition is that `k` be at least equal to `a+b`. Since we cannot increment `k` we set the variable `t` to the value of `k`. The `While` increments `t` until it is equal or greater than `a+b`. At this point, just using `t` by itself will return the value of `t`.

```
Clear[f];
f[a_, b_, k_ : 0] := 
  Block[ {t},
   t = k;
    While[t < a + b, t++];
    t
   ]
```